# jQuery UI 1.9.2 Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

is it possible to disable single headers in jquery ui 1.9? I had a quation runing about this, while i was using 1.8 and there it wasnt possible. I fond a way, but its really hard coded. It opens the tab and if the user doesnt have permitions to it , the tab closes. So is there any better way now?

best regrads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way and i thought ill share it hopefully it will help some one else a lot. :)

```
 $(function() {
     var icons = {
            header: "h3",
            activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
     };
        $( "#prod_accordion" ).accordion({
            active:<?php echo $db_obj->getValue('status') ? 'acc_'.$tab_status : 'acc_0'; ?>,
            icons: icons,
            autoHeight: false,
            beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
                var newIndex = $(ui.newHeader).index('h3');
                if (jQuery.inArray(newIndex , accordion_array) == -1) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

the `accrodion_array` is an array with indexes like (1,2,3,4) and i check if the index of the clicked accordion lets say 5 is in the array. If not then perventDefault() and the accordion header wont open.

- if u add `ui.addClass('ui-state-disabled');` to the accordion headers that are not in the array the user will now what accordion he cant open. :)